# Find and remove audio files which has less than 3 minutes of play duration

Tags: linux, find, audio

Is there a way to find and delete all the audio files recursively (MP3 files) which have less than 3 minutes play duration time?

Consider the situation that I have mixture of multiple format files (e.g. directories, text files and mp3 files).

Comment: Updated my question @don_crissti

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one way.  Run `mediainfo` against every mp3 file, if shorter than 3 minutes, delete it.

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in $(find . -type f -name \*.mp3); do
    [[ $(mediainfo --Output='Audio;%Duration%' "${FILE}") -lt "180000" ]] && rm "${FILE}"
done
```

Or for fans of one-liners:

```
find . -type f -name \*.mp3 -exec bash -c '[[ $(mediainfo --Output="Audio;%Duration%" $1) -lt "180000" ]] && rm "$1"' -- {} \;
```

Comment: What does the \ before `*.mp3` do here?

Comment: Prevents the shell from immediately expanding *.mp3.  Imagine you have foo.mp3 and bar.mp3 in current dir.  `find *.mp3 -ls` would result in the shell generating the line `find foo.mp3 bar.mp3 -ls` which would, of course fail with `find: paths must precede expression: foo.mp3`

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to cobble together a shell script as @dirkt mentions in his answer.

You can use `ffprobe` from the `ffmpeg` group to get duration in seconds -

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1  /path/to/mp3/file.mp3
```

You can use `find` to find all files ending in `.mp3` in a given directory and any/all subdirectories, and call a script providing the path/filename of any files found

```
find /search/from/dir -type f -iname "*.mp3" -exec /path/to/delete_if_short.sh {} \;
```

Create your `delete_if_short.sh` script - use the `ffprobe` command to check length, if under 180 (value is in seconds, so 3 minutes) then `rm` the file and you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of tools which can print out the play duration time of various audio file formats, e.g. `sox`, `mediainfo` and others. Which tool to use depends on the format of your audio files, which you didn't tell us.

You can process this output with `grep` etc., and use it in a shell script inside a loop as a condition whether to delete the file.

Comment: OP did say "(MP3 files)"

Comment: @number9 - no, that was after my comment (which was after dirkt's answer...)

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason my find-foo was not up to par, so I hacked one stackexchange answer of a find replacement and came up with this.

```
#!/bin/bash
# mytime is the number of seconds of the mp3 that you want to delete,
# in this case 3 minutes
mytime=180
files="$(find -L "<put your top level directory here>" -type f -name  "*.mp3")";
# are there any files at all?
if [[ "$files" == "" ]]; then
    echo "No files";
    return 0;
fi
echo "$files" | while read file; do 
    # take the file, find the time, convert to seconds
    times="$(mp3info -p "%m:%s\n" "$file" |awk -F':' '{print ($1*60)+$2}')"
    # if that is greater than 3*60, we delete the file, which is $file.
    if [[ "$times" -lt "mytime" ]]
    then
        # WARNING, there be dragons here... 
        echo "We are removing $file from the system..."
        rm "$file"
    fi 
done
```